# Issue on github stays closed after I deleted a pushed commit

Tags: git, github

I closed an issue via commit message of a commit. But then I decided to revert the pushed commit with the `git rebase` command. Deleting worked fine; `gitk` shows the cleaned history as intented.

However, in our githup repository, the issue is still closed and the referencing commit is clickable. That is, I can see what I did (and reverted).

Is this behaviour intended? How can I also clean the issue log after I have deleted a commit?

Comment: `git revert` is fine, but rewriting history that's already pushed is something you should **never** do. But either way, you have to reopen the issue manually, since it's not always desirable to reopen an issue after a revert.

Comment: Well, the only problem you face is that others maybe already pulled the changes and worked with it. In this case, however, I am the only contributor.

Comment: Just because you're the only contributor doesn't mean nobody clones your repo. A force push will cause trouble (although easy to fix if you know how to) even with an unchanged local tree.

Comment: My repo is private, too.

Comment: You should have started with that.

Comment: But still, I think there *are* reasons to rewrite history: https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/codebase/dev/git/clean-commits/

Comment: Anyone who clones your repo will hate you. But rewriting published history on feature branches is usually OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19656/discussion-between-merose-and-nyuszika7h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I received from github's support:

- Issues can't be reopened if the commit is removed from history but they will consider it as an improvement.
- Therefore issues have to be reopened manually.
- The commit will be visible (after clicking on the link in the issue's log) unless a garbage collection cycle removes it. The log will then say "Commit has since been removed from the repository and is no longer available."
- They can run a garbage collection cycle on a commit on request because the normal user cannot.